# How do I get a Windows process's current audio output level?

Tags: c++, windows, audio

I hope this makes sense, I am not sure how exactly I should word this...

Hi, I am trying to write a program that will be able to monitor the audio output of certain processes. I am having a hell of a time finding a way to actually do this. I have only been able to find ways to get the current volume level, but not the actual output level. I've been searching through Stackoverflow, but everything I've found is only able to fetch the program's volume control level (like the slider in the Windows Volume mixer, however I am basically looking to get the value of the fluctuating green bar in the mixer)

I basically want to check the output level of a program every x milliseconds and if it is above a certain threshold, run a method to do something. How can I do this?
Thanks!

Quick edit to be clear: Win 7+ with C++

Answer (score 1):

You probably want [IAudioPeakMeter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368239(v=vs.85).aspx)

This [sample app here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26357/Multimedia-PeakMeter-Control) looks promising.