# How do I get a Windows process's current volume value?

Tags: python

[How do I get a Windows process's current audio output level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37904595/how-do-i-get-a-windows-processs-current-audio-output-level)

quote:
I've been searching through Stackoverflow, but everything I've found is only able to fetch the program's volume control level (like the slider in the Windows Volume mixer, however I am basically looking to get the value of the fluctuating green bar in the mixer)

I:
Same question as above, but I'm looking for the Python way to get the fluctuating value of green bar for a certain process. Or it'll be better if the value can be obtained directly via API but not from the UI level.

```
from ctypes import cast, POINTER
from comtypes import CLSCTX_ALL
from pycaw.pycaw import AudioUtilities, IAudioEndpointVolume

# Get all active audio sessions
sessions = AudioUtilities.GetAllSessions()

for session in sessions:
    volume = cast(session._ctl.QueryInterface(IAudioEndpointVolume), POINTER(IAudioEndpointVolume))
    volume_level = volume.GetMasterVolumeLevelScalar()
    print(f"Process: {session.Process.name()}, Volume Level: {volume_level:.2f}")
```

Tried pycaw but no function works.